# Visual studio 2012 - debugging

Tags: c, debugging, visual-studio-2012

I very often hear that I should debug my code before asking questions. It seems to me that it's some useful functionality.

I tried to google something, but all I found were some strange console commands or other things like that. I'm not some kind of pro in C/C++, I'd like to try debugging short programs mostly < 200 lines.

What can I do with debugger? What are breakpoints?

How can I use debugger for simple tasks in visual studio 2012? How do I use breakpoints? (setting them doesn't change anything).

Comment: Look up `visual studio debugging` on youtube if you don't get how to do it from articles.

Comment: [Debugging in Visual Studio](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/sc65sadd.aspx)

Comment: Which manual are you reading? I have a feeling these questions are all answered by it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting them might not change anything if the code you marked with a break point didn't get any chance to run in the first place, make sure the execution gets to that piece of code and you can do that by setting another break point in the outer scope.

Comment: Well, the code doesn't compile, but I set breakpoint at the beginning of the main function.

Comment: if the code doesn't even get a chance to compile then you have errors in your code,, i mean syntax errors you'll find them underlined with red lines try to find them and fix them then it should compile.

Comment: So it stops on breakpoint only if code compiles?

Comment: first you need to do some research before you ask a question here otherwise you will be punished by the voting down as i noticed,, second if any answer helped you please mark it as the right answer its the big " right " mark below every answer rating you have and click the up arrow. this way we know that your problem is solved.

Comment: I had to wait a couple of minutes before marking it as accepted.

Comment: also you can navigate through code line by line when the break point is hit using F11 key on your keyboard and F10 the difference is that F11 Simply takes the " going through process " in more details.

Answer (score 0):

Using `VS2012`, set a breakpoint in your code and start Debugging using `F5`-key or press the small green `Play`-icon in the top-bar.
You can then step through your breakpoints and even single lines. There is plenty of stuff on this topic. Please see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/sc65sadd.aspx) for Debugging with `VS2012`.

Comment: How do I step through breakpoints? Start debugging just compiles everything.

Comment: Using `F5`-key you go to the next breakpoint. Just make sure the process reaches your code lines. Set some breakpoints sequentially to get a hang of it.

Comment: I placed breakpoints in every line and it doesnt stop anywhere.

Comment: Are you sure you started using solely `F5`-key? Have you started in `main` and checked every line after it?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure. The program just compiles the whole code at once.

Comment: Yes, it *must* compile all at once. You then step through it when executing.

Answer (score 0):

When you run your program in Visual Studio press F5 or select the 'Run Program With Debugger' option.

The debugger enables you to pause the code at a specific point (Line of Code) using breakpoints. You place a breakpoint on the line(s) of code you wish the program to pause. When the program reaches the line of code with a breakpoint it pauses. You can then use 'watch' variables to have a look at the value currently assigned to each variable. This is useful for instance if you have a large program and the actual output from the program is different to the expected output of the program. You can use the breakpoints to test the code by examining the values of data-structures at various points of the code and identify where your program may be going wrong.

You can also set 'exception' breakpoints. These are useful if your program causes an exception (crashes). An exception breakpoint will identify the line of code where the crash occurred which means you can then examine the line of code and try to identify why the program crashed.

Using breakpoints you can also 'step' through lines of code. This means you can run the program manually one line at a time by telling the debugger to step into the next line of code.

Answer (score 0):

When you're trying to compile your program and get an error because of punctuation issues (i.e. forgot a semi-colon or a brace) that's called a syntax error. Sometimes, a program can have a line of code that's *technically* written correct, but doesn't do what you want it to. So, you use a debugger to watch your program execute, and make sure that it's doing what you actually want it to.

If you want to debug a specific section of code, you set a breakpoint. When you're running your code in debug mode, a breakpoint tells the compiler to stop executing the code at that point. From there, you can examine the code line by line using step out, step into, or step over commands (Debug -> Step Into etc).